# Error initiating Equalizer,The app crashes sometimes

Tags: android

So i was trying to use equalizer but sometimes app crashes

Here are the necessary things to note

## 1) I am using sessionid 0;

## 2) App crashes when any other app is either using it,or has used it and i haven't restarted the phone since then

Strangely the line number which is causing the crash is not shown

here is the logcat

```
04-30 18:21:29.642: E/AudioEffect(31157): set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -38
04-30 18:21:29.642: E/AudioEffects-JNI(31157): AudioEffect initCheck failed -5
04-30 18:21:29.642: E/dalvikvm(31157): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale global reference 0x1d2002b2 (index 172 in a table of size 172)
04-30 18:21:29.642: E/dalvikvm(31157): VM aborting
04-30 18:21:29.642: A/libc(31157): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 31157 (thermusicplayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while using the visualizer class this is what helped me.
the status: -38 is a "errno.h" code(aka a POSIX error) you can check it out on this list I found. This list can be super helpful when debugging.
http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno
in your case 38 is a "function not implemented" error which is probably no fault of yours. I think it had to do with this bug.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33669
Which occurred in android 4.03-4 and I believe they have fixed in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```